# RecyclerView MemoryLeak - Leak Canary

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have the following LeakCanary where it appears that:

[image]

log:

> - Instance of .ui.flows.channelsflow.ChannelsFragment |   static $classOverhead = byte[764]@328963209 (0x139b9489) |
>     channelListAdapter = .ui.flows.ChannelListAdapter@332876376
>     (0x13d74a58) |   channelListArray = java.util.ArrayList@332876416
>     (0x13d74a80) |   channelListView =
>     im.ene.toro.widget.Container@332876440 (0x13d74a98) |
>     clickedChannelObject = null |   firstVisibleItem = 0 |   globalHelpers
>     = .managers.GlobalHelpers@316374608 (0x12db7e50) |   gridLayoutManager = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager@332877360 (0x13d74e30) |   loading = false |   mainViewModel = .ui.flows.MainViewModel@328888104
>     (0x139a6f28) |   playlistListView =
>     android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView@332877496 (0x13d74eb8) |
>     playlists = java.util.ArrayList@332878360 (0x13d75218) |
>     playlistsAdapter =  PublicPlaylistsAdapter@332878384 (0x13d75230) |
>     reportAlert = .ui.flows.ReportAlert@332878416 (0x13d75250) |   rxBus =
>     .rxkotlin.RxBus@316376312 (0x12db84f8) |   sharedPreferencesManager =
>     .managers.SharedPreferencesManager@328888696 (0x139a7178) |
>     totalItemCount = 22 |   userSavedSubscription =
>     io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable@332878520 (0x13d752b8) | 
>     viewModel = .ui.flows.channelsflow.ChannelsViewModel@332878536
>     (0x13d752c8) |   viewModelFactory = -
>     viewmodel.ViewModelFactory@316377792 (0x12db8ac0) |   visibleItemCount
>     = 4 |   visibleThreshold = 5 |   _$_findViewCache = null

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <im.ene.toro.widget.Container
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/primary_text_large"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code, we can't help you without it.

Comment: i update question @notTdar